# Including php code from another file inbetween your script

Tags: php

What I'm trying to do is fairly simply, but does not seem work.

In this main page, I'm trying to insert a piece of code from another page like so.

```
<?php

include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'\attach\common.php';

$clear = False;

echo $code;

if($clear){
    echo 'Clear was cleared';
}

?>
```

**This is common.php**

```
<?php

$code = "if(isset($_GET['n'],$_GET['c'])) {";
$code .="   echo 'Name and Country were set <br />';";
$code .="   $clear = True;";
$code .="} else {";
$code .="   echo 'An error occured <br />';";
$code .="}";

?>
```

How can I do this in php?

**Update**

```
<?php
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'\attach\common.php';
$clear = False;
d();
if($clear){
    echo 'Clear was cleared';
}
?>

<?php

function d() {
    if(isset($_GET['n'],$_GET['c'])) {
        echo 'Name and Country were set';
        $clear = True;
    } else {
        echo 'An error occured <br />';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: What is your error @jmenezes

Answer (score 1):

**Please be careful** using `eval()` as it's a very **dangerous** way of achieving what you want.

Why can't you just put code in `common.php` instead of putting it up as a string inside variable?

i.e. common.php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['n'],$_GET['c'])) {
   echo 'Name and Country were set <br />';
   $clear = true;
} else {
   echo 'An error occured <br />';
}
?>
```

-

In the case where you'd really need to do so:

Use `eval()` to parse `$code`. That's because your code is a string variable and not actual code.

```
<?php

include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'\attach\common.php';

$clear = False;

eval($code);

if($clear){
    echo 'Clear was cleared';
}

?>
```

Comment: Put it in common.php? It's already in common.php. What you see is an example. The realy thing is huge with 12 GETS etc. Hence this approach.

Comment: I meant the exact same thing as Hanky 웃 Panky did. Just don't put code as a string like this `$var = "echo('code inside a string');die('is very bad');";`

Answer (score 1):

You don't put code in a string to include it in another file, just put the code as it is.

`common.php` should be

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['n']) && isset($_GET['c'])) {
echo 'Name and Country were set <br />';
$clear = True;
} else {
   echo 'An error occured <br />';
}

?>
```

Comment: I did that because there's other code in there as well. Not just this piece.

Comment: This isn't a valid reason IMO. Just learn the right way of doing it. Putting code inside a variable is never the solution.

Comment: So put all of that code outside any string, the more the code the more the reason to keep it as it is an not enclose it in a string. That's a complete overkill which will make your life tough if you ever have to debug anything

Comment: Also not that for simple codes you can surely use eval but as things get complicated you will find it hard to go around the concept of having all your code in a string, your server might not like this either for heavy loads

Comment: Hmm... So If I put all code in there without strings, how will I be able to echo or eval only the part I need? There is other code being used on other pages.

Comment: That's not the way to go about programming. Time to get back to basics. You don't include all the spaghetti codes to every single page. Pages should include only the code that they need  to use. And also the fact that certain code blocks are called whenever needed even if they are present. Its not that every line of code will produce an output necessarily every time. This is very very very basic concept of programming, and if you are doing it the string way, i'm sorry but you are heading the wrong way.

Comment: I've updated my question. Hope the updated approach is ok? Does the function need anything else like a return?

Comment: Yes now its good. You need a return only if you want to send back data to the point from where the function was called. So if you need to echo something based on function's response then send a return value. Currently you have an echo in the function so return is not necessary for that.